# Are posts with more than one question allowed?

Tags: discussion

To put it simply, are posts with more than one question allowed? I have seen a few posts that do this, but the questions are usually related so I don't flag them or anything. I assume that if the questions are related, it is okay. I'm still pretty new so I'd like to be sure.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In general, we prefer to do it one question per post, as it were. If they're tightly connected topics, sometimes it works out okay, but in general, answers get too long and it gets too muddled as people only answer some parts of what was asked and not others.

As always, the intent is to make a giant repository of awesome info on the internet, and part of that is making clearly defined, easily findable information, which is why we generally split things up as much as possible into one question per post. :)

Comment: It's always a judgement call. stuff like *"Are there bows/arrows in Fallout? If so, where are they located?"* should be fine, whereas *"Are there bows/arrows in Fallout? and how do I defeat Super Mutants without Power Armour?"* should not be.

Comment: That's what I thought. n00bs gotta be sure!